# CSS set width of first element only regardless of its element name

Tags: css, css-selectors, width

Here is some XML...

```
<style type="text/css">
    .center:nth-of-type(1):firstchild {width: 100% !important;}
</style>

<div class="center">
    <subjective_element_name>//This element's width should be set
        <subjective_element_name>//This element is NOT a direct child, not set
        </subjective_element_name>
    </subjective_element_name>
</div>
```

I want to force the *first* element that is a child of the `.center` element to have a `width: 100%;` declaration. I do not want it to occur more than once on any other elements (the `.center` selector only exists once). That means the selector should only match the `subjective_element_name` element above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.center > *:first-child {
   /*rules here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
.center  > * {width: 100% !important;}
```

The difference between Kei's answer and my own is that only the first element will be effected where as if there are ten different *direct* child elements they will all be effected. So depending on what someone needs either answer will likely help someone somehow.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @nietonfir: How is "Figured it out: <solution that he figured out>" not a complete answer? Does the asker not have the right to answer their own question?

Comment: My answer worked fine for myself so I posted it, Kei's worked too so I accepted his since he posted before I did.